# Merging data frames on timestamp great than or equal

Tags: python, pandas

I have two 2 pandas data frames:

```
timestamp1 = ['2018-10-01 00:01:49.800000000', '2018-10-01 00:01:52.900000000', '2018-10-01 00:04:18.857741600'] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(timestamp1, columns =['timestamp']) 

timestamp2 = [['2018-10-01 00:01:50.230 ', 'John'], ['2018-10-01 00:01:52.560', 'Jill'], ['2018-10-01 00:04:19.100', 'Jack']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(timestamp2, columns =['timestamp', 'name'])
```

I want merge the two frames based on the timestamp (t) where t from df1(t) >= df2(t). The output I'm looking for is:

```
         timestamp_df1,               timestamp_df2,                name
2018-10-01 00:01:49.800000000      2018-10-01 00:01:50.230          John
2018-10-01 00:01:52.900000000      2018-10-01 00:01:52.56           Jill
2018-10-01 00:04:18.857741600      2018-10-01 00:04:19.100          Jack
```

The timestamp is the only common thing in the data frames that I can merge on. I've looked into conditional merging but it seems like it's not the right route? Any help or advice would be useful!

Comment: For the first and third row the condition is not met I believe? Or am I understanding something wrong? You basically want to merge on the closest value to timestamp_df1 for the values greater or equal on timestamp_df2, right?

Comment: take a look at `merge_asof`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) here. Note though that in the second case the condition does not hold. You can also add a tolerance as I'm doing here:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, 
              on='timestamp', 
              direction='nearest', 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1min'))

     timestamp  name
0 2018-10-01 00:01:49.800000000  John
1 2018-10-01 00:01:52.900000000  Jill
2 2018-10-01 00:04:18.857741600  Jack
```

Comment: Great - I think this is the answer. However, based off of what i've just read, should it be 'nearest' instead of 'forward'?

Comment: Wouldn't it be backward, since OP is asking for df1 to be >= df2? for the first row, 00:01:49 <= 00:01:50

Comment: 'Nearest' here is needed. The forward only takes the next timestamp in the row, not the one that's closest to it :)

Comment: I think it should be backward as @ivan points out, though it seems as your expected output does not match the requirement?

Comment: Yep @user47467 looks like it! Updated

Comment: Cool thanks - will accept the answer once I'm allowed to!